# Matching a string with vimscript that starts with _

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to conditionally load files in vim/neovim with Vimscript, except where the filename is prefixed with an underscore. It's not working 100% yet, instead all the files are still loading:

```
for filename in split(globpath('~/.config/nvim/plugins', '*.vim'), '\n')
  if filename !~ "^_"
    exe 'source' filename
  endif
endfor
```

Sort of works with `file !~ "_"`, but that matches with the underscore anywhere in the string. I need ignore only filenames that **start** with _.

Comment: `^_` is the right pattern for "string starts with `_`". `if filename !~ "^_"` is truthy if `filename` *doesn't start* with `_` and falsy if it *starts* with `_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a trivial mistake here, I assumed the filename contains something like `_filename.vim`, but instead the string contains the path as well, `/Users/someuser/blah/_filename.vim`.

I fixed it by splitting the path, and checking only the last element in the array:

```
for filename in split(globpath('~/.config/nvim/plugins', '*.vim'), '\n')
  if split(filename, "/")[-1] !~ "^_"
    exe 'source' filename
  endif
endfor
```